# iOS - Keyboard hides UIAlertView with UITextfield

Tags: ios, hide, uialertview, uikeyboard

I have a `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField`. I want the user to type in something and tap `OK`. But when the keyboard appears, it hides the buttons of the `UIAlertView`. Is there a way to make the `UIAlertView` move when the keyboard is shown. Or just move it upward so the buttons will be seen by the user?

This is the code I use:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Other", nil] ;
alertView.tag = 2;
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
CGRect frame = alertView.frame;
frame.origin.y = -140;
alertView.frame = frame;
alertTextField.text = @"some text";
[alertView show];
```

Comment: Hi. I dont know if alert view can be positioned itself, but maybe you can put it in to the scroll view and when user tap textfield it just scroll to the visible area for you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if alert view can be positioned itself, but maybe you can put it in to the scroll view and when user tap textfield it just scroll to the visible area for you.